# What Stack Exchange site should I use to find a program that meets certain needs?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I need to know where I can post a question of the following nature: In search of online program that does X, Y, and Z.

Specifically I am trying to find an online email client that has the ability to forward to webhooks built-in. Therefore, no coding (scratch Stack Overflow), no server setup (scratch Server Fault), and no solutions that involve my computer specifically (scratch Super User).

Can anyone point me to the right Stack Exchange site?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like a job for [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Make sure you [follow their advice](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) about researching and explaining what you need and why.

Comment: though, SR involves stuff you run yourself. This almost feels like it needs the mythical SR equivilent for webapps?

Comment: I took a look before posting, and they have several open questions asking for web apps, and the How To Ask doesn't say it must be something you install.